# C - advance position indicator of a stream manually using fgetc

Tags: c

Is there any way to move indicator position of a file steam manullay using the function [fgetc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgetc.htm) ?
As the documents say the function move it each time I call it, but what if I want to get the next character of the file inside the loop?
Here's the code and what I'm trying to do:

```
for(;;) {
    c = fgetc(file);
    if ( feof(file) ){
        break;
    }
    next_char = ; // How do I get this??

    /* Check if we are in a middle of a decimal number */
    if ( c == '.' ) {
        if ( isdigit(next_char) && prev_char && isdigit(prev_char) ) {
            in_decimal_number = true;
        }

    }
    if ( isalpha(c) || isdigit(c) || in_decimal_number ) {
        // some stuff here
    }
    if ( in_decimal_number ) {
        in_decimal_number = false;
    }
    prev_char = c;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to read the next character in the file? Calling `fgetc()` again will get you   the next character to. If you don't want to consume it for the next loop you could seek back a spot after reading `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR)` would do it. But since the next time through the loop you're going to read that char anyway seeking seems pointless better of just saving the value locally.

Comment: Umh, use `fgetc`? If you need to look at two characters at a time, move the "next" to the "current" on every iteration. i.e. something like `curr = fgetc(); while(...) { next = fgetc(); do_something(curr, next); curr = next; }`

Comment: `int ungetc(int c, FILE *stream);` lets you put the data back in the buffer, but you could also alter the program logic to work with the last input instead of the current input.

Comment: Curious, why did you code `if ( feof(file) ){
        break;
    }` instead of `if (ch == EOF) break;`?  They are _almost_ equivalent.